# A /dev/null equivilent for DISPLAY when the display is just noise

Tags: null, xserver

I'm running a java app which creates a visual display of some of the things it is doing, while it is doing it. However, I'm want to run this in a script that won't have a display to attach to. In the current environment, there isn't even a DISPLAY environment variable set. I tried to simply set my DISPLAY to :0.0. But that doesn't exist. I don't really care about the display. I just want the app to process the files silently.

Since I can't just turn the display off(not my app), I'm left with trying to get around the need for display.

Is there a black hole that I can send the DISPLAY to? an equivalent to /dev/null?

I searched around for a bit on the web, but the words I could think of to use: "display" "null" "disregard" etc are all two generic to get me to an answer.

This is the middle of a larger script, so I want the rest of the output to stdout to be available.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a headless X server called [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). It's basically what you need since it accepts X clients but basically does nothing with the data from them. From that linked page (slightly paraphrased):

> `Xvfb`, the X virtual framebuffer, is a display server implementing the X11 display server protocol.
>
> In contrast to other display servers, `Xvfb` performs all graphical operations in memory without showing any screen output.
>
> From the point of view of the client, it acts exactly like any other X display server, serving requests and sending events and errors as appropriate. However, no output is shown.
>
> This virtual server does not require the computer it is running on to have a screen or any input device. Only a network layer is necessary.

If you can't find that, then another possibility would be to use a spare PC with a full CygWin install. CygWin comes with a full-blown X server which you could connect your application to (and just ignore it). You could even set it up as the corporate /dev/null DISPLAY.

But I'd look into Xvfb first.

Comment: This worked out really well for me. It is Xvfb. The box isn't mine, but the administrator was nice enough to put it on the box.

Comment: Thank you!  I've always wanted to be able to run gschem to produce PDFs and PNGs of my schematics on my build machine, but it hasn't worked without X (which is a pain in the butt).  Now with Xvfb there's an X server for it to connect to!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, use:

```
xvfb-run JAVA_COMMAND_LINE
```

Depending on your version and flavor of Linux, there may be [one line you have to change](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=624510) in xvfb-run to get everything to run.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Xvfb and works very well to run applications which require a X server in ssh sessions.

To complement previous answers, I use two main ways to run Xvfb:

1. Run `Xvfb` in a specific port and configure the terminal to use this port:

   ```
   Xvfb :10
   export DISPLAY=:10 
   YOUR_COMMAND
   ```
2. Use `xvfb-run`:

   ```
   xvfb-run YOUR_COMMAND
   ```

Comment: Nice! Big shout out for answering a question that is over a decade old!    I've come to SO so many times and every little bit of context in all the answers has helped me. So I hope this extra bit helps someone else too.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a java program you can use the headless mode to run the application.

Try to run it with `-Djava.awt.headless=true` parameter, like this if it's a jar file:

`java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar jarfile.jar`

[More about headless mode...](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/)

Comment: I did not get a chance to make this approach work. I tried, but received a headless exception still. No doubt if this little app was written right, I could have used this flag.

Comment: @Marc: `java.awt.headless=true` just tells the JVM that no display is available. Some Java APIs can handle this, and continue working, some cannot, and throw `HeadlessException`. So whether it works depends on what the program does. See [Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)(by Artem Ananiev and Alla Redko, June 2006 ) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xvfb, as noted above. That way, you will never see the output (you can use a tool to take screenshots, though).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb
http://packages.debian.org/sid/xvfb

Or you could set up a VNC server. Under Linux, a VNC server is implemented as a special X server that can be accessed via VNC, insstead of displaying on a local monitor. That gives you a headless X server, with the added bonus that you can connect to it via VNC just in case you *do* need to see what's going on.

http://www.tightvnc.com/vncserver.1.html

vncserver is a nice wrapper script for (tight)VNC, which makes starting a VNC server a breeze. Most distros should install it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run a VM on the target machine? Then you could set your DISPLAY to that. Or you could try vnc (currently on a machine which doesn't allow this or I'd try it...).